# Vertical Flip Animation through XML

Tags: android, xml, animation

So I followed the guide towards creating animation in XML.
My problem was I had difficulty on flipping it back again upright. Apparently after a scale, the scale resets and what was upside down is now declared upright which I find weird. My solution is below this question.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">

    <scale
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.75" />

    <set>
        <scale
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fromXScale="1.0"
            android:fromYScale="0.75"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:startOffset="1000"
            android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0" />

        <set>
            <scale
                android:duration="1000"
                android:fromXScale="1.0"
                android:fromYScale="0"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:startOffset="2000"
                android:toXScale="1.0"
                android:toYScale="-1.0" />
        </set>
    </set>
</set>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wrong:**

```
fromScaleY="-1.0"
toScaleY="1.0"
```

**Right:**

```
fromScaleY="1.0"
toScaleY="-1.0"
```

**My Solution:**

```
<scale
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="-1.0" />
```